# React.js .push() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a total rookie when it comes to React and this is most likely a simple issue, but it nearly drove me nuts.

**The code is following:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Tile extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            priceLog: [],
            diff: 'equal'
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps() {
        let log = this.state.priceLog;
        log = log.push(this.props.price);
        this.setState({ priceLog: log });
        console.log(this.state.priceLog);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Tile">
                Company: {this.props.name}<br/>
                Price: {this.props.price}
                <div className={this.state.diff}></div>
                <button id={this.props.id}>Details</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Tile;
```

I get `"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): log.push is not a function"` when the component is rendered. All properties passed to the component are strings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Besides the answer from @CD, you do not want to directly manipulate a `state` outside the designated `setState` method. In this case you could use `concat` to return a new array and assign that to the state variable. Something like this

```
this.setState({ priceLog: this.state.pricelog.concat(this.props.price)});
```

And your second call to the `console.log` might not deliver the desired results since `setState` is an asynchronous call. If you want to access the new state variable you have to use a callback like this

```
 this.setState({
     priceLog: this.state.pricelog.concat(this.props.price)
 }, () => console.log(this.state.pricelog));
```

Comment: @DavidGevorgyan Do you mean the syntax `() =>`? That's a shorthand from es5 for the `function()...` call. If you want to use that you need to enable es5 in your project.

Comment: Thank you! Used this style instead:

    this.setState({ 
        priceLog: [...this.state.priceLog, this.props.price] 
    }, () => console.log(this.state.priceLog));

Answer (score 10):

[`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array so replace:

```
log = log.push(this.props.price);
```

with:

```
log.push(this.props.price);
```